# What does "the storm booming without in solemn swells" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "the storm booming without in solemn swells" mean?(from Moby Dick)

Comment: It means exactly what each of those words means. This is General Reference at its finest.

Comment: @tchrist Well, *without* isn't used in its most common sense, so that's probably the confusion (although comparison with *within* shouldn't make it too difficult).

Comment: @WChargin Just because *without* isn’t here used in its most frequently used way as a preposition doesn’t mean its adverbial use isn’t definitively covered by any general reference that gives words’ sense. They do and it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only tricky part of the sentence is 'without', which in this context means 'outside'. 'Swells' are waves, although it might also refer to an increase in noise, which is sometimes also called a 'swell'.